# PHP DI and casting interface

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

I do not understand, for example I'm using php-di container,
I have ClassA and ClassB, both of them are implements Intreface1
And I'm creating objects of this two classes thru DI

Now when I'm injecting ClassA to the constructor I need inject exactly this class, which crate a dependency of this classA, not an Intreface1

Can I somehow say that this particular ClassA should implement intrefeca1 ? 
In docs of PHP-DI I found

```
  // mapping an interface to an implementation
    'LoggerInterface' => DI\create('MyLogger'),
```

But I do not understand how it works, LoggerIntreace it's just a string which   maps this text to to the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject "by interface"

example with monolog and php-di, you say :

```
use Monolog\Logger;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
...
  LoggerInterface::class => \DI\autowire(Logger::class)
```

and now in your constructor, you can inject

```
public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
```